# Сформировать php-массив из результатов ajax-запросов

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Задача такая - на сайте выводится список номеров в отеле, у каждого номера есть форма с выбором кол-ва этих самых номеров. При нажатии кнопки на каждой форме осуществляется ajax-запрос. Смысл в том, что надо сделать так, чтобы при каждом запросе значение добавлялось в массив. На данный момент результат каждого запроса становится нулевым элементом массива, затирая предыдущий результат. Это и ясно - скрипт отрабатывает однажды, а следующий запрос работает по-новой. 
Сам пытался в обработчике реализовать запись в БД, но почему-то не работает.

Форма:

```
<form method="get" class = "formx" data-id="<?php echo get_the_ID();  ?>"  action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call(this)">
    <p>
        Кол-во бронируемых номеров:
        <select id="room_num_search" class="room_num_search" name="room_num_search">
            <?php for($i=1; $i <= $show; $i++): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i;  ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
            <?php endfor;  ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="check_in" value="<?php echo STInput::request('start'); ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="check_out" value="<?php echo STInput::request('end'); ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="adult_number" value="<?php echo STInput::request('adult_number'); ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="extra_bed" value="<?php echo $max_adult_number-intval(STInput::request('adult_number', '')); ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="child_number" value="<?php echo STInput::request('child_number'); ?>"/>
    <input name="action" value="hotel_add_to_cart" type="hidden">
    <input name="item_id" value="<?php echo $item_id; ?>" type="hidden">
    <input name="room_id" value="<?php echo $room_id; ?>" type="hidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="start" value="<?php echo STInput::request('start'); ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="end" value="<?php echo STInput::request('end'); ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="is_search_room" value="<?php echo STInput::request('is_search_room'); ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Выбрать">
</form>
```

Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function call(form) {
        var msg   = jQuery(form).serialize();
       // var form_id = jQuery(form).data('id'); alert(form_id);
        jQuery.ajax({
            // Метод передачи
            type: 'POST',
            // Файл которому передаем запрос и получаем ответ
            url: '<?php echo 'path/to/ajax.php'   ?>',
            // Кеширование
            cache: false,
            // Верямя ожидания ответа, в мили секундах 1000 мс = 1 сек
            timeout:3000,
            data: msg,

            // Функция сработает при успешном получении данных
            success: function(data) {
                // Отображаем данные в форме
                jQuery('.results').each(function(i){
                    if(jQuery(this).data('id') === jQuery(form).data('id')){
                        jQuery(this).html(data);
                    }
                })
            },
            // Функция срабатывает в период ожидания данных
            beforeSend: function(data) {
                jQuery(".results").html('<p>Ожидание данных...</p>');
            },
            // Тип данных
            dataType:"html",
            // Функция сработает в случае ошибки
            error:  function(data){
                jQuery(".results").html('<p>Возникла неизвестная ошибка. Пожалуйста, попробуйте чуть позже...</p>');
            },
        });
    };
</script>
```

ajax.php

```
global $wpdb;
$res = $wpdb->get_results("INSERT INTO `multiple_booking` (`room_num_search`)
       VALUES ($_POST[room_num_search])");
        echo "INSERT INTO `multiple_booking` (`room_num_search`)
        VALUES ($_POST[room_num_search])";
```

Comment: $_POST['room_num_search'] как минимум

Comment: @KirillKorushkin , так это да, в самом файле ajax.php сформируется и выведится в элементе с классом results. В мне нужно, чтобы при каждом новом запросе данные записывались в таблицу

Comment: нет, у вас в примере элемент массива $_post - room_num_search не обернут кавычками

Comment: @KirillKorushkin , вот так?
global $wpdb;
$room_num_search = $_POST['room_num_search'];
$res = $wpdb->get_results("INSERT INTO `multiple_booking` (`room_num_search`)
        VALUES (`$room_num_search`)");

Всё равно ничего не изменилось

Comment: Тут почему-то не отображаются мелкие косые кавычки

Comment: @KirillKorushkin, сам запрос я распечатал и протестировал через sql в phpmyadmin - там всё работает.Проблема начинается тогда, когда я в ajax.php пытаюсь вызвать любую функцию

Comment: "Проблема начинается тогда" в чем выражается эта проблема?

Comment: @u_mulder , в том, что функции не вызываются в обработчике. В данном случае не срабатывает ф-ция get_results . И, как следствие, мой скрипт выводит сообщение: "Возникла неизвестная ошибка. Пожалуйста, попробуйте чуть позже..."

Comment: Неизвестная ошибка скорее всего 500-я, открывайте логи и смотрите что не так.

Comment: @u_mulder , "неизвестная ошибка" - это сам скрипт такое сообщение должен напечатать, если по каким-то причинам ф-ция function(data) не сработает в js .Она как раз и не срабатывает почему-то

Comment: @u_mulder, вы правы, ошибка 500 , но о чём мне этот вывод говорит?
500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.js:4
ajax @ jquery.js:4
call @ (index):3773
onsubmit @ (index):1

Comment: Откройте пожалуйста консоль разработчика в браузере и посмотрите ответ от вашего скрипта `ajax.php`.

Comment: О том что надо открыть логи, прочитать их и __выяснить причину 500-й ошибки__

Comment: @u_mulder , ajax.php ссылается на вот этот код, якобы тут что-то не так:
                try {
                    u = 1,
                    j.send(s, x)
                }
Я в js не силён просто, а задача вот попалась (

Comment: Дело не в джсе. Дело в php-скрипте. Вы открыли логи? Не в браузере логи, а на __сервере__.

Comment: @u_mulder , посмотрел логи, ни одного упоминания ajax.php или файла с формой, с которой идёт запрос

Comment: @u_mulder , я так и не понял почему выдавалась ошибка, мне кажется, из-за global $wpdb - глобальной переменной для подключения к БД WordPress, сделал по-обычному, средствами php, где всё заработало:
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
$room_num_search = $_POST['room_num_search'];
$query ="INSERT INTO `multiple_booking` (`room_num_search`)
        VALUES ($room_num_search)";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

Comment: И так сойдет. Не можешь разобраться - пиши все с нуля.